# Can't install Oracle JDK in Linux Mint 19.2

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, java, jdk

I have downloaded Oracle JDK 11 and I'm trying to install it on my Linux Mint (x64). After downloading the tarball, I extracted it to my /usr/lib/jvm and exported it to PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.5/bin/java
```

but if I try to:

```
java -version
```

bash says:

```
zsh:command not found: java
```

There are something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `which java`, you will see that it's linked to `/usr/bin/java`, which is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/java`. To change the default java version, you need to run the `update-alternatives` command. You will see output similar to this:

```
    $ update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Now, since you installed via a tarball and not a PPA (as Oracle Java is not part of the Mint repos), this method for Oracle Java won't work since the java installation is not registered with the system. If you plan on switching between Java versions, I would recommend finding a PPA and installing that way.